Так всё же "неуверенный в себе", или "не уверенный в себе"?
Как я понял из того, что прочитал на просторах сети, то приставка "не" зачастую создает новое по смыслу слово, а частица "не" лишь отрицает стоящее перед ней выражение. 
Возьмём, к примеру, слово "неумеющий", означающее что-то вроде человека неспособного, у которого ну прям ничего не получается, к чему бы он ни прикасался, и, например, причастие "не умеющий петь". Здесь всё понятно - во втором случае мы пишем "не" отдельно, так как есть зависимое/распространяющее слово "петь".
Та же самая ситуация наблюдается и в таких примерах:
незнающий/не знающий грамоты
неспособный/не способный на преступление
Здесь мы прям можем проследить эту смену смысла, но как дела обстоят с парой "неуверенный" и "не уверенный/неуверенный в себе"?  Или лучше взглянуть на примеры в страдательном залоге? 
Мне тяжело представить себе, на самом деле, что конкретно "неуверенный" будет означать, если будет применено по отношению к человеку. Типа, каков он - неуверенный человек? 
Наверное, если взять наречие "неуверенно", означающее образ действия колеблющегося, сменяющегося в каком-либо смысле, то и человека можно так охарактеризовать: как постоянно сбивающегося с пути, верящего то в одно, то в другое, или что-то в этом роде. 
В этом плане, конечно, мне больше видятся такие словосочетания, как "неуверенная походка", "неуверенная речь", но думаю, что и "неуверенный человек" имеет место быть.
Если следовать логике "зависимого слова", то логичнее было бы предположить, что написание должно быть раздельное, ведь мы отрицаем словосочетание "уверенный в себе", а не хотим создавать новое по смыслу слово и привязывать к нему зависимые слова, ведь так?...(или я что-то не так понимаю?) 
У Розенталя на это я накопал два правила, которые немного конфликтуют друг с другом, как мне кажется: 

раздельное написание "не" при наличии зависимых/поясняющих слов 
слитное написание "не" в случае, если причастие используется в значении прилагательного ДАЖЕ при условии, что есть зависимые слова 

Что именно имеется ввиду, когда мы говорим об "использовании причастия в качестве прилагательного"? Я так полагаю, что подразумеваются те случаи, когда нам нужно именно то прилагательное, которое образуется при слиянии "не" и изначального слова, то есть новообразованное прилагательное, с новым смыслом?
В его примерах (пункт 5_):

веками нетронутая земля: "нетронутая" означает то, что на ней никто не жил?
ложь преступника так бесстыдна, порой так неприкрыта: "неприкрыта" означает "ясна/очевидна"? 

Если так, то скорее всего нам следует оставить раздельное написание, если всё же присоединение "не" к "уверенный" создает новое слово, то есть, если "неуверенный" подразумевает неуверенность во многих вещах, общую неуверенность, склонность к колебаниям, то человек не может быть "неуверенным в себе", так как это бы насильно сузило смысл изначального прилагательного "неуверенный"? 
Заранее благодарю за прочтение данной "котлэтки", которую я сотворил, и жду ваших мыслей/комментариев!

Ответ на этот вопрос есть в словаре. Это прилагательное, на него не действуют зависимые слова, судя по правилам и по словарю:
   НЕУВЕРЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -рен, -ренна, -ренно. 1. Такой, 
   которому не свойственна уверенность в ком-, чём-л.; 
   нерешительный. Человек он был робкий, н. Н. в себе. Н. в 
   правильности решения. // Выражающий нерешительность, 
   свидетельствующий об отсутствии уверенности. Н. ответ. Он 
   подтвердил согласие неуверенным кивком. Сказать 
   неуверенным голосом. 2. Нетвёрдый, неустойчивый. Н-ая 
   походка. Сделал несколько неуверенных шагов. Неуверенно, 
   нареч. Н. отвечать, взглянуть. Чувствовать себя н. Она 
   ходила ещё н.

Приведен пример: неуверенный в себе.
Розенталь
 6. Наличие пояснительных слов, как правило, не 
 влияет на слитное написание частицы не с 
 прилагательными (ср. написание не с причастиями): 
 незнакомый нам автор; неизвестные науке факты;

